# Problems with memory dynamic allocation: main: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc

Tags: c, list, memory, malloc, valgrind

I'm writing a simple function to create a list which represents a deck of cards.
Here's the definition of the structs

```
typedef struct {
 float valoreEff;
 char *seme;
 char *valore;
 } carta;

struct Mazzo {
 carta info;
 struct Mazzo *nextPtr;
 };


typedef struct Mazzo mazzo;
typedef mazzo *mazzoPtr;
```

Here's the function which returns a pointer to the first element of the list

```
mazzoPtr caricaMazzo(void){

 mazzoPtr sMazzoPtr=NULL;
 int val,seme;
 carta buffer;
 mazzoPtr newPtr;
  char *tabValori[10]={"Asso","Due","Tre","Quattro","Cinque","Sei","Sette","Donna","Cavallo","Re"};
  char *tabSeme[4]={"Denari","Spade","Coppe","Bastoni"};

 for(seme=0;seme<4;seme++){
  for(val=0;val<10;val++){
   buffer.seme=tabSeme[seme];
   buffer.valore=tabValori[val];
   if (val<=7) {
    buffer.valoreEff=val+1;
   }
   else {
    buffer.valoreEff=0.5;
   }
   printf("ok\n");
   newPtr=malloc(sizeof(carta));
   if (newPtr==NULL){
    printf("Memoria insufficiente\n");
    return NULL;
   }
   newPtr->info=buffer;
   newPtr->nextPtr=sMazzoPtr;
   sMazzoPtr=newPtr;
  }
 }
 return sMazzoPtr;
}
```

GCC gives me no compile-time errors, but when I execute the program, this is the output

```
ok
ok
main: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
&((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd))))
&& old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)
((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *
(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size
& 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

I've also tried Valgrind, but I can't figure out the mistake in the code.

```
==21848== Invalid write of size 4
==21848==    at 0x8048554: caricaMazzo (in /home/gianluca/Dropbox/PROGRAMMI/progetto/main)
==21848==    by 0x8048431: main (in /home/gianluca/Dropbox/PROGRAMMI/progetto/main)
==21848==  Address 0x419e034 is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==21848==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==21848==    by 0x804851D: caricaMazzo (in /home/gianluca/Dropbox/PROGRAMMI/progetto/main)
==21848==    by 0x8048431: main (in /home/gianluca/Dropbox/PROGRAMMI/progetto/main)
==21848==
```

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be at the line where you call `malloc()`.

`newPtr` is of type `mazzo*`, but you are allocating space for a `carta`, which is too small.

I think it should be `newPtr=malloc(sizeof(mazzo));`

Comment: As an aside - you can often prevent this type of error by using the idiom of `newPtr=malloc(sizeof(*newPtr));` - that way the type for whatever the pointer is can't help but be correct.  And someone reading the code later doesn't need to jump around in the source to make sure the type of the `sizeof` operand is correct for the pointer being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be an option for you, you would be better off using C++. Among its many software engineering benefits, its `new` idiom for allocating memory prevents exactly this kind of error, since you must explicitly use the object type: `newPtr = new mazzo;`